# Как в post-запросе retrofit 2 скормить строку с парамтрами?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, graphql

Делаю демку в которой необходимо сделать post-запрос в виде graphql(запрос в виде json).
Знаю что есть нормальный конвертор graphql для retrofit но сейчас совсем некогда с ним разбираться срочно нужно выдать результат! :(
Поэтому необходимо что-то типа:

```
String a = "value";
String b = "value";
String urlParameters  = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
String request        = "http://example.com/index.php";
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
                .add(urlParameters) //Как я вижу эту строку
                .build();
```

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь и совет!

Comment: `builder.addQueryParameter`?

Comment: Можно весь код потомучто в Retrofit.Builder() такого нет

Comment: Что-то такое https://gist.github.com/mandybess/dca2e8a0527aff2d8e0688c17297c945

Comment: сейчас поробую и вернусь:)